# How to use @Assert\Type("float")?

Tags: symfony

With Symfony 5, I have entity with @Assert\Type("float") :

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", nullable=true, precision=6, scale=3)
 * @Assert\Type("float")
 * @Assert\PositiveOrZero()
 */
private $premium;

/**
 * Get premium
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPremium(): ?float
{
    return $this->premium;
}

/**
 * Set premium
 *
 * @param float $premium
 */
public function setPremium(?float $premium): void
{
    $this->premium = $premium;
}
```

I have a form for this entity :

```
public function buildForm(
    FormBuilderInterface $builder,
    array $options
): void {
    $builder
        ->add('premium', MoneyType::class, [
            'label' => 'label.premium.price',
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'required' => false,
        ])
    ;
}
```

But when I validate the form with **9.99**, I have this error :

> ERROR This value must be of type float.

When I `dump($value)` in `vendor/symfony/validator/Constraints/TypeValidator.php` :

> "9.990"

I think my form sends a `string` rather than a `float`, but I am surprised that Symfony does not manage this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is a string in an HTTP request, data types are meaningful only inside an application.

Anyway, to manage this case you need to attach an implementation of `DataTransformerInterface` that checks the data (if it's a string, is numeric, etc) and then casts the value to a float number.